# (Bash) For Loop Not Functioning Properly

Tags: bash, for

I have a loop in a bash script, `test.sh` that reads as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

CHOSEN_NQUEUE=0

foo(){
 for chunk in $(seq 0 $((${CHOSEN_NQUEUE}-1)));
    do
        echo "CHUNK = $(($chunk+1))"
 done
}

bar(){
  CHOSEN_NQUEUE=10
  foo
}

bar
```

This loop has previously been working fine up till now. If I run the program as `. test.sh`, I get the following error code in the loop:

```
-bash: 0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9+1: syntax error in expression (error token is "1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9+1")
```

If I run the program as `bash test.sh`, then the function produces the desired result:

```
CHUNK = 1
CHUNK = 2
CHUNK = 3
CHUNK = 4
CHUNK = 5
CHUNK = 6
CHUNK = 7
CHUNK = 8
CHUNK = 9
CHUNK = 10
```

This is a snippet from a much larger program; if I run this program with `bash program.sh`, the error I see in the first case persists.

Particularly, if I simply run `foo`, then the error does not occur. If I run `foo` from `bar`, then the error occurs. This occurs irrespective of using `bash program.sh` or `. program.sh`.

Can someone kindly suggest what I might be doing wrong? Is it poor practice to run functions from inside other functions in bash?

Kindest regards!

EDIT:

Thanks to everyone in the comments!

Upon realizing this problem arises from using select for arrays, I attempted the following code:

```
select opt in "${options[@]}"

    do
            next=false
            local IFS=@
            case "@${options[*]}@" in
            (*"@$opt@"*)
                    foo
            (*)
                    echo "Invalid option: $REPLY"
                    ;;
            esac
            echo ""
    done


    echo "IFS = $IFS"
```

The problem arises from `IFS=@`, which should not be @ outside of the loop.

However, if I run this code attempting to set `IFS` locally, i.e. `local IFS=@`, it appears the global `IFS` is modified. The code outputs:

```
IFS = @
```

Does anyone have an idea why this might be?

Kind regards again!

Comment: for me the given code is working well...

Comment: You would get that error if you double-quoted the command substitution of `seq`, i.e. `for chunk in "$( seq ... )"`.  Could you double check that you are showing us the code that you are running?

Comment: The whole thing is 2000 lines long - I can do this if it would help?

Comment: check what your `IFS` is in the working and the non-working case. Put something like `printf "IFS: %q\n" "$IFS"` in front of the `for` loop

Comment: The output it simply `IFS: @` in the non working case and IFS: $' \t\n' in the working case

Comment: Then u should have changed/assigned IFS to @ in somewhere in the nonworking script...

Comment: Then, something is changing IFS before the `seq` command. Probably (not knowing all the details of the 2000 lines script) you can re-set `IFS=$' \t\n'` to its default value.

Comment: @Isaac `IFS` is probably set to a non-default value in the interactive shell. What I would want to know if why they are sometimes sourcing the script and sometimes not.  That part makes no sense.

Comment: Or better yet, since this is bash, do the change local to the function: make the first line of `foo` read `local IFS=$' \t\n'`. The value will return to what it was before when the function exit.

Comment: Perfect solutions! I had set `IFS=@` to allow some menus to run. Changing instances of `IFS=@` to `local IFS=@` where necessary solved the problem.

Comment: @Kusalananda From this OP comment: *If I run foo from bar, then the error occurs. This occurs irrespective of using bash program.sh or . program.sh.* it seems to me that the `program.sh` is allways executed (not sourced) but at some point while testing the script `test.sh` (not `program.sh`) at some point the user executed `. program.sh` which trigered the un-noticed change of IFS, and, thus, his description. ... In any case, a `local IFS=$' \t\n'` inside foo makes the script more robust.

Comment: @Isaac Well, it makes the code in question _work_. Other statements in the scirpt may break due to `IFS` having been changed from `@`...

Comment: I have tried setting the local IFS, but there remains a problem.

Comment: @Kusalananda I believe in the motto: **enforce your assumptions**. The function `foo` was written under the  assumption that expansions would be split on spaces, setting IFS enforces that assumption. That breaks nothing else (if changed with local) outside foo, not even if IFS was/is @. That IFS got changed, or not, at some other point of the script should be corrected, also, at some other point of the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you get indicates that `$chunk` contains a multiline value, all the numbers from 0 to 9. That would happen if word-splitting *doesn't* happen on the result of `$(seq ...)` in the `for`.

Now, the usual way to prevent word-splitting is to put double-quotes around the expansion, so `for chunk in "$(seq ...)"` wouldn't expand. But that's not the case here since you'd know if you added double-quotes, and anyway, it works in *some* cases.

But word-splitting isn't always the same, it's based on the value of `IFS`, which by default contains a space, tab and a newline (`$' \t\n'` using the C-style quoting). If it contains something different, then those are the characters that will be taken as word separators.

And indeed you have modified `IFS` inside the `select`, just before calling `foo`:

```
local IFS=@
case "@${options[*]}@" in
(*"@$opt@"*)
        foo
```

The way the variable scoping works in Bash is that `foo` also sees the modified value of `IFS`. `local` doesn't mean the change is visible only to that function, but instead it's also visible to all subfunctions called from that level too:

```
$ x=999
$ a() { echo "a: x=$x"; }
$ b() { local x=$1; a; }
$ b 123
a: x=123
```

This is unlike what you'd have in, say, C.

---

A workaround would be to save `IFS` to another variable instead, so something like this:

```
local oldifs=$IFS
IFS=@
str="@${options[*]}@"
IFS=$oldifs
case $str in ...
```

or to change it in a subshell (hiding the `IFS` change there):

```
str=$(IFS=@; echo "@${options[*]}@")
case $str in ...
```

You could also make a function to do that string join (hiding the `IFS` change in the function), you just need name references to pass variables by name:

```
# join a b c:
# join the values of array 'a' with the character 'b', and put the result in 'c'
join() {
    local -n _arr=$1
    local IFS=$2
    local -n _res=$3
    _res="${_arr[*]}"
}
src=(11 22 33)
join src @ dst
echo "$dst"        # outputs "11@22@33"
```

(Of course, that's a bit unwieldy for one use, and name references aren't perfect either: a nameref *inside* a function can't refer to a variable with the same name *outside* it (at least in Bash 4). The minor upside of this over just using a command substitution is avoiding a fork to start the subshell.)

Or, just to be on the safe side, (re)set `IFS` every time you need it. Inside `foo`:

```
foo() {
    local IFS=$' \t\n'      # or just IFS=$'\n'
    for chunk in $(seq ...); do
        ...
}
```

Comment: A perfect answer once again! Thank you for the help.

Comment: Note that you do not **have** to change IFS: `str="@$(printf '%s@' "${options[@]}")"`

Comment: @Isaac, yep, that seems like a pretty good alternative.